# Update a document library field using a remote event reciever

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a created a remote event handler that I want to use to update a field called "Summary" in a document library when a document is added or changed.

I have used the following code:

```
public class RemoteEventReceiver : IRemoteEventService
 {
    public SPRemoteEventResult ProcessEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
    {
        SPRemoteEventResult result = new SPRemoteEventResult();
        if (properties.EventType == SPRemoteEventType.ItemAdding ||
            properties.EventType == SPRemoteEventType.ItemUpdating)
        {
            // Update the Summary field
            result.ChangedItemProperties.Add("Summary", "BANG!");


            result.Status = SPRemoteEventServiceStatus.Continue;
        }
        return result;
```

This doesn't update the field.  It is based on the following code http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2013-Add-list-2c6e71e0#content which works perfectly for me.

Any ideas what I am missing would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the internal name of Summary field?

Comment: Hi Nadeem, thanks for your reply. Yes, I have checked the internal name is just "Summary" (I did this by looking at the URL on editing the field).

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, and it worked for me.
Try to add a new ordinary text-column, name it "Test", and try to set the value with:

```
result.ChangedItemProperties.Add("Test", "bang!");
result.Status = SPRemoteEventServiceStatus.Continue;
```

Just to test out the event.

For me it didn't work inside:

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.CreateRemoteEventReceiverClientContext(properties)){ }
```